# Angular 8 Lazy Load Module - Can't Navigate

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having the hardest time. I've setup what I think is the proper structure but the app isn't allowing me to navigate and worse, it's presenting me with the same page. I'm trying to navigate to /login but nothings working.

App Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ///// OPEN ROUTES /////
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  ///// AUTHENTICATED ROUTES /////
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  ///// FEATURE MODULES (LAZY LOADED) /////
  {
    path: "clients",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./clients/clients.module").then((m) => m.ClientsModule),
  },

  ///// CATCH ALL ROUTES /////
  { path: "not-authorized", component: NotAuthorizedComponent },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

Clients Routing Module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ClientsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ":id",
        component: ClientDetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ":id/edit",
        component: ClientEditComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "add",
        component: ClientAddComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The nav page simply has a routerLink="/login" on the A link

#

EDIT

Forgot to unload the ClientsModule from the main app module, so, it was loading twice.

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console?

Comment: No weirdly no error.

Comment: Let me ask another question if you don't mind, I'm unable to now navigate to /clients/add. I'm using navigateByUrl('/clients/add') and it remains on the main clients page, never changes. It feels like the router is matching the first route and stopping for some reason.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Do you have router-outlet in app.component.html
2. The client routing module is incorrect. More specific routes go to the top, and less specific routes go towards the bottom:

   `children: [
     { path: "add", ... },
     { path: ":id", ... },
     { path: ":id/edit", ... }
   ]`

Comment: Doesn’t a lazy loaded module need to start with an empty route as the prefilled and assumed route comes from the app routing module. Where I specify clients

Comment: Also. If I implement another router outlet it all works. One for main app and one for lazy children. Is that correct or can I load all routes in the main router outlet ?

Comment: One router-outlet in the main component is enough. If you already have one there and it's still not working, then you might need to put a minimum reproducible code on stackblitz to take a look at.